# getting NODE_ENV from firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been unable to get NODE_ENV from firebase functions, it seems it doesn't exist. Can anyone confirm this? The docs doesn't seem to be very helpful.

It seems actually that the only 2 variables that are setted are [image]

If anyone has a clue on this please feel free to contribute.

Comment: "there are only two values you should use for NODE_ENV, either production or development", so, I guess I'm wondering why firebase functions would ever be running with that parameter set to development?

Comment: Because I want test the functions by setting different environments in the backend. 
I usually run locally things, test it and then I send it to production :)

Comment: You should be able to stand up a `-dev` version of your function to test against.  In other words, create 2 functions.

Comment: This seems very counter productive. An environment variable is certainly a better idea in my opinion, as a matter of fact I guess it is the correct approach.

Answer (score -2):

See [Set environment configuration for your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

> #### Environment configuration
>
> Often you'll need additional configuration for your functions, such as third-party API keys or
>   tuneable settings. The Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions offers
>   built-in environment configuration to make it easy to store and
>   retrieve this type of data for your project.
>
> `firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY"
>   someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"`

Also check GCP Cloud Functions documentation, [Using Environment Variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var).  Looks like you can add them from the GCP CLI, maybe same for Firebase Functions?

> `gcloud functions deploy envVar --runtime nodejs8 --set-env-vars FOO=bar --trigger-http`